# How to get the correct XPath for Google Sheets formula ImportXML

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I tried to set up importXML in my Google Sheets, I used the method to copy full Xpath.
It seems not working at all.
After reading Xpath still not sure how to get the right path just for the token price.
Hope can get some idea or document to read to get the value I need.
Thanks a lot for reading this.
Wish you to have a nice day.

=IMPORTXML("https://info.osmosis.zone/token/DSM","/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/p")

Comment: Data comes from here `https://api-osmosis.imperator.co/tokens/v1/DSM` and returns as JSON. You could use a custom json parsing function such as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/master/ImportJSON.gs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page contents

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

JavaScript content is not supported by any IMPORT formulae. the best course of action would be to find a different source for your scrapping.

**You need to use a specific url (api) which contains the json.**

### edit :

According to the url provided by @QHarr and if you want to retrieve all informations from url, try

```
function parseValues(url) {
  const jsn = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  const headers = Object.keys(jsn[0]);
  return  ([headers, ...jsn.map(obj => headers.map(header => Array.isArray(obj[header]) ? obj[header].join(",") : obj[header]))]);
}
```

and in your sheet

```
=parseValues("https://api-osmosis.imperator.co/tokens/v1/DSM")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, at least now I know this webpage done by Python :)

Comment: I have edited my answer if you want to retrieve all values from the url

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom function by:

- Opening Script Editor (Tools > Script Editor or Extensions > Apps Scripts)

And then enter the following within the script:

```
/**
 * @return Specific value out of the value of different fields
 * @customfunction
 */
function PARSEVALUE(Url,itemKey) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(content);
  return jsonObject[0][itemKey];
}
```

In your spreadsheet, use the function like:

```
=PARSEVALUE("https://api-osmosis.imperator.co/tokens/v1/DSM","price")
```

There are different values for different keys, as in `price`,`symbol`,`name`,`liquidity`,`volume_24h` e.t.c. you can grab using this function.